# R: how to convert table of various types to text columns for export

Tags: r, excel, multiple-columns, corpus

[image]

I have 2 columns of data, in table loaded from Excel: ID, BeforeConv
containing number and text, respectively.
After loading this data  from Excel to R studio i made some tm_map based text cleaning on column BeforeConve copy applied to the new column in RStudio: AfterConv

```
This is my code:
x <- read_excel(file.choose())
corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(x$BeforeConv))
corpus<-tm_map(corpus,tolower)
x$AfterConv<-data.frame(text = sapply(corpus, as.character)) //<-here in R  studio data displayed correctly yet
write.csv(x=x, file="R2test.csv") //<-now the data displaced
```

my issue is that while in R studio  i see the conversion correct(see image below)

[image]

...when exporting to either CSV or XLSX that last column (AfterConv) displays totally messy data (see below). What i did wrong and how to fix it?

[image]

Best if i could see the proper code to convert last column correctly to export it correctly along with two exiting columns to Excel or CSV.

Comment: Could you run `dput(x[1:20,])` and paste the output here?

Comment: Here it is - limited to the length of comment allowed: structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), BeforeConv = c("This is text before conversion", 
"Another Text before con", "OTHER TEXT", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AfterConv = structure(list(
    text = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("another text before con", 
    "other text", "this is text before conversion"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", (...)